# How to know which port you're connecting FROM when connecting TO an IP + Port combination?

Tags: networking, port

I've been asked to connect my app to client's SQL Server available via VPN.

I'm comfortable in network user-space, connecting to IPs via a port for a specific application. MySQL connects via 3306, etc. We have custom apps listening on port 8919 for HTTP requests.

The client has asked us to state which port we're connecting FROM so they can modify the firewall accordingly.

Since I never set this I'm unaware of how to determine that. Is the port allocated automatically or is possible to set a FROM port for certain connections (e.g. SQL)?

Comment: It depends on how the app/software was coded... generally, software usually uses whatever arbitrary port >`1024` that's not in use for outbound requests, unless the software has been coded to use a specific port, which isn't common due to the obvious _(say software is hardcoded to use port `10123` - if that port is in use when the software goes to use it, the connection will fail)_. Is the initial connection not initiated by the client, which would allow the client to configure a port redirect for the listening port on your app? If it's not a public VPN, this can be configured via the VPN.

Comment: To be more precise, unless the application requests otherwise, the source port will be selected from the _ephemeral port range_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the source port is allocated automatically. It is never recommended to rely on it being a specific value or even from a specific range.

When working directly with sockets, you *can* request a specific local port by calling *bind()* before *connect()*. The "local IP address" field can be left as all-zeros.

(Similarly, you can retrieve the local address and port that were assigned for the connection by calling the *getsockname()* function. This is only possible after the connection has been established, and of course the local port will be different every time you connect.)

But when working with higher-level client libraries such as MySQL, often the library provides no way to request binding to a specific local port. After all, doing so is *very* rarely useful, and building security policies based on it just makes no sense. (For that matter, many client libraries don't even support binding to a specific local address, which *would* be quite useful...)

Comment: I found both this and harrymc's answer helpful but it doesn't let me green tick both

Comment: @user3168961: You can still upvote.